# Understanding View Controllers

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an TabBar application with 4 tabs. All four tabs have navigation controllers. In the settings tab i have a table with a cell for "Feedback". When the cell is clicked a FeedBackView controller is pushed which contains a feedback form with a few fields. This has a textfield for Category. When the textfield is touched, a modal view controller (FeedBackModalView) is presented with a picker. In the viewDidLoad method of the FeedBackModalView controller I typed `NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController).` In the console it shows the parentViewController as TabBar controller. Why is that? Shouldn't it be showing the FeedBackView controller as the parentView since I'm presenting the modal view in that controller?

I hope i was clear.

Comment: What object are you hoping to gain access to? Perhaps someone can point you to the variable that accesses it.

Comment: I wanna access the FeedBackView controller from the modal view. It has a method which will set the category textfield after the category in selected in the picker. In simple view based applications i cud use [self.parentViewController setCategoryText] (setCategoryText defined in the FeedBackController). But in this one the parentViewController is a tabBarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `presentModalViewController` with UITabBarController has some issues, and I believe the internal behavior of the method has kept changing in recent SDK versions. The bottom line is, you are supposed to use the root view controller to modally present a view controller. In case you are using tab bar interface, that becomes the UITabBarController object.

In an old version of SDK, when I presented a modal view in a view controller inside a tab bar controller the modal view did not appear in full screen, which wasn't an expected or a documented behavior. Now a modal view seems to appear in full screen anywhere, and I wouldn't be surprised if `[self presentModalViewController:animated:]` method internally checks `self` and if it has non-nil `parentViewController` property, send the message to the parent view controller (which will explain your observation).

My memory is vague and perhaps somebody has to correct me. However, I still believe it's the straightforward thing to understand (and also maybe practice) `presentModal...` only works with the root view controller.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was wondering, is there a way to obtain the rootViewController from any view?

Comment: No 'built-in' method to get the view controller, so you need to make communication between the root vc and other views yourself. Those views are probably retained by the view of the root vc, which, of course, is retained by the root vc. So don't create a retain cycle by retaining the root vc in some view objects. You could assign (not retain) the root vc to a property of a view, which basically means that the root vc becomes a delegate of the view object. Delegating is a good practice in this case, but you could also use notifications or KVO instead, if it meets your needs.